# How to connect AWS EC2 instance to our network domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, tfs

I have installed TFS 2017 in AWS EC2, my problem is that I cant add users from our network domain to that TFS Server.

I dont have much knowledge in setting up in Active Directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-your-on-premises-active-directory-to-aws-using-ad-connector/

Comment: @David Reyes Have you resolved the issue? any update?